# Is unix file path a valid URL?

Tags: url, protocols, specifications

Suppose we have a string `/path/to/file`, when I use `urlparse` of Python, it will treat the string as a valid URL and return the following result:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
urlparse('/path/to/file')
# ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/path/to/file', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

But if I do the same thing with JavaScript, it will throw the following error

```js
new URL('/path/to/file')
// Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

I am wondering which implemetation is right. Shall a unix file path treat as a valid URL? I don't dive in to the RFCs, but personally I prefer the way of Python as it makes it clear to distingiush local file or remote resource by parsing it and checking the `scheme` field. It's useful when you write a program that allow use to load file from local or remote.

**Update:**

According to the document provided by Alexei Levenkov
: [The Fine Manual on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) it says

> url: A string ... that represents an absolute or relative URL. If url is a relative URL, base is required, and will be used as the base URL. If url is an absolute URL, a given base will be ignored.

In JavaScript it will not throw error if `base` parameters is provided

```js
new URL('/path/to/file', 'file://')
```

But it still have gap with the implement of python when input string is a relative path `./path/to/file`.

In JavaScript it will ignore the `./` but Python will still keep it.

JavaScript:

```js
new URL('/path/to/file', 'file://')
new URL('./path/to/file', 'file://')

// both yeild the same result:
// URL {origin: 'file://', protocol: 'file:', pathname: '/path/to/file'}
```

Python:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
urlparse('/path/to/file')
# ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/path/to/file', params='', query='', fragment='')

urlparse('./path/to/file')
# ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='./path/to/file', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: I've added your research inline in the question, please make sure to clarify what exactly you need explanation with (probably "what are absolute and relative urls").

Comment: *"I am wondering which one is right, by saying right I mean not against the specification of URL."* What other source of truth would you suggest?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738) should be the specification of URL.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just find that some programming languages will treat unix file path as a valid URL and parse it successfully, but some will not. I throw this question because I am working with a project that need to load data from local file or remote HTTP url. I am looking for a graceful way to get it done.

Comment: My question is: you want to know *"which one is right"*, but not *"against the specification of URL"*. What do you consider to be "right" then?

Comment: I try to update the question. I think all program laugage should respect the same specification and return with the same result. But in fact Python and Javascript yield different result for the same string and I want to know which one should be right.

Comment: We're going in circles here. It depends on what you consider to be your source of truth. If you base yourself solely (as JavaScript does) on the [URL Living Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/), JavaScript is more "right", both in the sense that it requires a base URL to parse a relative URL, and in the fact that it strips off the leading `.` from the URL's path. Python's [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) is more opaque in the sense that the implementation is based on an interpretation of the aforementioned standard plus 6 other RFCs.